OpenSSH Vulnerabilitites remediation
This is in line with the OpenSSH Vulnerabilities
is openssh 8.9p1 ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6 CVE's fixed in openssh 8.9p1 ubuntu-3ubuntu0.7 ?

Did you check the CVEs against the Ubuntu Security Team's CVE Tracker?

You do know you can look at the changelog which tells you what is installed in the newer versions of packages; knowing your release of course will be required for accurate details (you didn't provide it; but a quick look shows you're likely using either an EOL release or outdated packages)
